# How to unmarshal xml data from online xml file

Tags: xml, go

I have an xml file on suppose https://www.notre-shop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml and I want to unmarshal this xml in my go code so I did this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var Product struct {
    Locs []string `xml:"url>loc"`
    Name []string `xml:"url>image:title"`
}

func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("https://www.notre-shop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml")
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    err = xml.Unmarshal(data, &Product)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for x, _ := range Product.Name {
        fmt.Println(Product.Name[x], Product.Locs[x])
    }
}
```

But this doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete code https://play.golang.org/p/pZ6j4-lSEz on play.

Comment: could you paste the code in play. BTW, you check for err on `ReadAll` and `Unmarshal`

Comment: I have added it. play doesnt allow http requests though.

Comment: It works for me. I see you edited your question and in the original question the code had a `log.Fatal(err)` without the if that checks if the error is actually there. As soon as I changed that it worked fine. So your code works :)

Comment: It doesnt print anything for me. Can you show me the output you get? I dont get any output at all

Comment: @lucapette which version of go are you using `go version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code which works for me (note: you could also use `ioutil.ReadAll` and `xml.Unmarshal` as you had before, instead of `xml.Decode`):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
//    <url>
//        <loc>
//            https://www.notre-shop.com/products/test-product-releasing-soon-2
//        </loc>
//        <lastmod>2017-01-17T08:04:44Z</lastmod>
//        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
//        <image:image>
//            <image:loc>
//                https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0624/0605/products/NOTRE-CHICAGO-QK9C9548_fde37b05-495e-47b0-8dd1-b053c9ed3545.jpg?v=1481853712
//            </image:loc>
//            <image:title>Test Product Releasing Soon 2</image:title>
//        </image:image>
//    </url>
// </urlset>
type URLSet struct {
    XMLName string `xml:"urlset"`

    URLs []URL `xml:"url"`
}

type URL struct {
    Loc   string `xml:"loc"`
    Image Image  `xml:"image"`
}

type Image struct {
    Title string `xml:"title"`
}

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.notre-shop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err) // log.Fatal always exits the program, need to check err != nil first
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var urlSet URLSet
    if err = xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&urlSet); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    for _, url := range urlSet.URLs {
        fmt.Println(url.Loc, url.Image.Title)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the XML Specification says

> ```
>  The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [XML Names] assigns a meaning 
>  to names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors should not 
>  use the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes, but XML 
>  processors must accept the colon as a name character.
> ```

This is the XML Namespace Recommendation says

> The XML Namespaces Recommendation expresses universal names in an
>   indirect way that is compatible with XML 1.0. In effect the XML
>   Namespaces Recommendation defines a mapping from an XML 1.0 tree where
>   element type names and attribute names are local names into a tree
>   where element type names and attribute names can be universal names.
>   The mapping is based on the idea of a prefix. If an element type name
>   or attribute name contains a colon, then the mapping treats the part
>   of the name before the colon as a prefix, and the part of the name
>   after the colon as the local name. A prefix foo refers to the URI
>   specified in the value of the xmlns:foo attribute.

You may not use name with colon(:) to get the inner elements rather you can avoid the pefix ,here is your code re-written

And for performance/memory considerations since you are getting a `io.Reader` you may use `xml.Decoder` instead of xml.Unmarshal.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var Product struct {
    Locs []string `xml:"url>loc"`
    Name []Image  `xml:"url>image"`
}

type Image struct {
    Title string `xml:"title"`
}

func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("https://www.notre-shop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    err = decoder.Decode(&Product)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for x, _ := range Product.Name {
        fmt.Println(Product.Name[x].Title, Product.Locs[x])
    }
}
```

Here is play link [play](https://play.golang.org/p/SNqyB3ZyH-)

Comment: @dmportella In play http get wont work.It is a security consideration.You may copy paste t and try